# Lightweight solution to block outbound connections from a specific app?

Tags: windows-xp

Since [I've realized windows xp's firewall can't block outbound traffic](https://superuser.com/questions/95939/how-can-windows-xps-firewall-be-made-to-block-a-specific-application), I need a lightweight solution to block a specific app.
Something along the lines of "little snitch" on OSX would be a great, but I can't find an alternative.
I really wanna avoid running a bloated firewall ala zone alarm for doing just this, so maybe there are lighter weight solutions around...

Know of a lightweight and fast application for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be as lightweight as it gets (memory footprint of both programs: around 5MB):

> Nirsoft's **[CurrPorts](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/cports.html)** is
>   network monitoring software that
>   displays the list of all currently
>   opened TCP/IP and UDP ports on your
>   local computer. For each port in the
>   list, information about the process
>   that opened the port is also
>   displayed, including the process name,
>   full path of the process, version
>   information of the process (product
>   name, file description, and so on),
>   the time that the process was created,
>   and the user that created it.
>
> In addition, **CurrPorts allows you to
>   close unwanted TCP connections**, kill
>   the process that opened the ports, and
>   save the TCP/UDP ports information to
>   HTML file , XML file, or to
>   tab-delimited text file.
>
> CurrPorts also automatically mark with
>   pink color suspicious TCP/UDP ports
>   owned by unidentified applications
>   (Applications without version
>   information and icons)

*CurrPorts is freeware and portable (no installation required).*

If you're looking for a 'real' firewall application for XP, have a look at **[iSafer](http://isafer.sourceforge.net/)** (a portable version is available [here](http://www.winpenpack.com/main/download.php?view.548)).

*iSafer is free open source freeware.*

Comment: Unless I missed something this won't prevent the connection from going through by prompting you.

Comment: well, you will have to create a rule in iSafer, there's nothing 'automatic' to it, the price of 'lightweight', you know. :) you didn't specify in your question that you want a program prompting you to approve each and every network connection, for this you'll need indeed a fully-fledged "firewall ala zone alarm'. however, iSafer is very easy to setup and use, check the 'English guide'.

Comment: Glad you edited your post, as iSafer is just what I needed, thanks.

Comment: took me a moment, couldn't remember the name ... but you're quite welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

[This site](http://www.iopus.com/guides/free-firewall.htm) recommends [Comodo](http://www.personalfirewall.comodo.com/).

I use it on one of my PC's and it seems OK. It's not as good (in my opinion) as the old Sygate Personal Firewall, but that's been subsumed into Symantec's Norton Internet Security which hardly counts as lightweight.

Comment: Thanks, I just grabbed Sygate's old offering, and it's working nicely, using only 12mb of RAM, I'll stick with it unless someone comes up with an even lighter one...

Comment: @Julien - I didn't know you could still download it. Where did you get it from?

Comment: http://www.filehippo.com/download_sygate_personal_firewall/

Comment: Cheers - I thought I'd lost my installer, but when I came to download it I found it. I must get round to replacing Comodo.

Comment: Comodo used to be a fine software firewall ... up to 2.6.5 or so. then came version 3 and that was the end of it, never touched it since (although i hear it has 'improved').